# MongoDB. Map-Reduce finalize function

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I want to calculate users with accumulating by dates. I have the following map reduce functions:

```
var m = function(){
    // creation date
    var d = new Date(parseInt(this._id.toString().slice(0,8), 16)*1000);
    // ticks
    var t = d.getTime();
    emit(d2,d3);
};

var r = function(k,v){
    return v[0];    // just go next with ticks
};

var opts = { out :  { merge : "UserAccum", db : "Metric"},
    finalize: function(k,v){
    var str = "parseInt(this._id.toString().slice(0,8), 16)*1000 <= "+v;
    return db.User.count({$where:str});         
} 
};
var res = db.Provider.mapReduce(m, r, opts);
```

When run, I get error:

```
Sat May 12 17:47:23 uncaught exception: map reduce failed:{
    "assertion" : "invoke failed: JS Error: TypeError: db has no properties
nofile_b:2",
    "assertionCode" : 9004,
    "errmsg" : "db assertion failure",
    "ok" : 0
}
```

Looks like it's not possible to call db. methods inside finalize. 
Why?

I knoq that I can call from map() and from reduce()

Comment: yes, because I don't accept answers.
My questions is usually "Why", but not "How"

Comment: If it answers your question, you should accept it. This helps future readers and rewards the answerer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can't run queries in map-reduce functions. They must depend only on their input parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can run queries within the mapreduce functions, it's just that db is a reference to the default database not automatically the database you are running against.

So you need to do this:
var fdb = db.getSiblingDB('yourdb');
var results = fdb.yourcollection.find(..);

I don't know whether this is new and didn't work in the version a year ago. Also "can" in this case may be different from "should."

Comment: Just a note: even if this is possible, don't do it. It'll go away if you upgrade to 2.4 and in the mongodb documentation it specifically says: "The map function should not access the database for any reason." and "The reduce function should not access the database, even to perform read operations."